# If $a \in A$ is not a prime number, then $A/aA$ is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

If $a \in A$ is not a prime number, then $A/aA$ is not an integral domain:

**proof**

$a$ not  prime, therefore:

$a \mid bc$ and $a\nmid b$ and $a\nmid c$

Therefore $b+aA \neq aA$ and $c+aA \neq aA$

But (b+aA)(c+aA) = aA

**According to my professor that concludes the proof**

My question is: if $b+aA = aA$ or $c+aA = aA$ would they be the absorbing element of $A/aA$?

In that case, the proof would make perfect sense to me

Comment: What is $\;A\;$ ? Apparently a commutative ring with unit...why not write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absorbing (or zero) element of $A/aA$ is $aA$.

Therefore if $b+aA=aA$ you just get the trivial equality $0.(c+aA)=0$ in $A/aA$.